# AngularJS - Range search

Tags: dictionary, angularjs, range, marker

I'm quite new to AngularJS but it's absolutely perfect for my project.

Here's my problem:
My customer has a static coded map (not google). On this map, we have 15 clothing reseller (hardcoded).

My json file:

```
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Laden Dortmund",
    "zip": 12345,
    "stadt": "Dortmund",
    "land": "DE",
    "left": "200px",
    "top": "300px"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Laden Unna",
    "zip": 45568
    "stadt": "Unna",
    "land": "DE",
    "left": "250px",
    "top": "400px"
}
]
```

and so on...
With "left" and "top" I'm marking my map with a marker:

```
<div class="map" ng-controller="DealerDetailListCtrl">
    <a class="marker" id="{{marker.id}}" style="left:{{marker.left}};top:{{marker.top}}" ng-repeat="marker in dealer"></a>
</div>
```

This is working good for ALL of the entries.
Now our customer wants a postal code search for the entries. Like:
 - Reseller1 (Postal Code: 45525) -> Shall be placed in this region of the map.
 - Reseller2 (Postal Code: 12345) -> Shall be placed in region xx of the map.
and so on.

**What I need is:**
Is it possible with Angular JS to have a search box like this:

```
<input type="text" name="postalcode" class="postalcode" ngRequired>
```

and to search for (in example) "45525" and I get all markers that are +/- within this postal code?
Maybe every entry will get two new nodes "RangeStart" (Start:40000") and "RangeEnd"(End: 50000") and if I search for "45525" all entries will be displayed, where the search term ins withing the range.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe possible with a custom filter? Anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you thinking of adding a "zip" attribute to each marker object in that JSON so that "Laden Dortmund" would have a zip of 23456 for example?

Comment: Damn, I accidentally deleted this row (the json entry is much longer than this example). There IS a zip attribute... (will edit it right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was baking an apple pie so I couldn't get back with you quicker, but this is possible with a custom filter as you mentioned in your comment.

```
myApp.filter("zipFilter", function() { return function(markers, zipCode) {

    var retMarkers = [];
    var lowRange = parseInt(zipCode, 10) - 1000;
    var highRange = parseInt(zipCode, 10) + 1000;

    // console.log('low: ' + lowRange);
    // console.log('high: ' + highRange);

    // loop through all the markers
    for(var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var singleMarker = markers[i];
        // if the marker falls within the range (+/- 1000)...
        if(singleMarker.zip >= lowRange && singleMarker.zip <= highRange) {
            retMarkers.push(singleMarker);
        }
    }

    return retMarkers;
}});
```

See it working online here http://jsfiddle.net/CWcxL/7/ and try typing in "44100" and see how it filters out the results based on a range of zip codes (in this case, +/- 1000 from whatever was entered).

Best of luck!

Comment: It's working great. I have modified it a little bit. Is it somehow possible to add the "country" drop down into the filter? I got an input for the zipcode and a dropdown with "DE, AT, CH" for the countries. Can I easily add the countrymodal into the filter as an parameter?

Comment: and it shows me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" of the variable "markers".

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem and I can show you how - can you share the link to the code you were working on? (jsfiddle perhaps?)

Comment: And just because StackOverflow doesn't like chatting in comments, we should move this to their [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21919/discussion-between-trevor-senior-and-marek123).